# Polar equations of circles and ellipses

Tags: conic-sections

I have been trying to convert some conic sections from rectangular to polar form.  I am fine going the other direction (given polar, convert to rectangular), but am having trouble going the opposite direction.

First of all, is it possible to convert ANY ellipse or circle into polar coordinates?  All the examples I see online have a center on one axis or another if not at the origin.

The two I am trying to convert are:

$$(x-4)^2 + (y-4)^2 = 1$$

and

$$\frac{(x-4)^2}{9} + \frac{(y-4)^2}{4} = 1$$

This is for a project using equations to create a picture.

Thanks!

Comment: do you want the origin for your polar coordinates to be the center of the ellipse?

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polar_coordinate_system#Circle

Answer (score 0):

Let $x-4 = 3\cos \theta$, and $y-4 = 2\sin \theta$ for the second equation, and

$x-4 = \cos \theta$, and $y-4 = \sin \theta$ for the first one.